# Setting external CSS for QWebView with resource file

Tags: qt4, qt4.7

I'm trying to set external CSS for QWebView with:

`ui->webView->settings()->setUserStyleSheetUrl( QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/default.css") );`

Which contains only:

`body { color: red; }`

But it's not working on any page ( nothing is in red )

Also i double checked by:

`ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->toHtml();`

But no CSS was applied.

Comment: The path `":/default.css"` specifies a file stored as a compiled resource. Is that your intention?

Comment: @ArnoldSpence yes , I use a Qt's resource file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, `QUrl::fromLocalFile` does not work with resource files. The problem and a workaround is discussed in [this forum thread](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7439):

> Not only the qrc scheme is (usually) not associated with any
>   application, but remember that resources are compiled inside your
>   executable. How is a 3rd party program supposed to access them?
>
> A workaround could be copying the file from the resource to a
>   temporary file/directory and then use QUrl::fromLocalFile +
>   QDesktopServices::openUrl.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution is to use

```
ui->webView->settings()->setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl("qrc:/filename.css"));
```

Using QUrl::fromLocalFile() is not at all necessary if you're opening the resource from within the application itself. Writing it to an external file isn't needed unless the URL is being passed to an external application.